# Binding and chaining multiple CollectionViewSource displaying items but causing binding errors

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, data-binding, windows-store-apps

My databinding seems to be showing items, but it is causing binding errors in the output logs so it seems it is wrong. I'm basing this off of Microsoft sample here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh758322.aspx

I have the collection views as page resources, the initial one, GroupCV is bound do the Groups property of the page's DataContext (view model), and seems to not give any errors.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <!-- Collection of items displayed by this page -->
    <CollectionViewSource 
        x:Name="GroupsCV"
        Source="{Binding Groups}"/>

    <CollectionViewSource 
        x:Name="TypesCV"
        Source="{Binding Types, Source={StaticResource GroupsCV}}" />

    <CollectionViewSource 
        x:Name="ProductsCV"
        Source="{Binding Products, Source={StaticResource TypesCV}}" />

</Page.Resources>
```

Here are the UI items i'm binding to. Like i said, everything seems to 'work', items show up in each column and clicking between them  updates the respective columns.

```
    <Grid x:Name="PopupChildInner"
                      Margin="20"
                  >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <!-- All Groups -->
                    <StackPanel Margin="5" Grid.Column="0">
                        <TextBlock Text="Product Categories"/>
                        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GroupsCV}}" 
                            DisplayMemberPath="Title"/>
                    </StackPanel>

                    <!-- All Types -->
                    <StackPanel Margin="5" Grid.Column="1">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title, Source={StaticResource GroupsCV}}"/>
                        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource TypesCV}}" 
                            DisplayMemberPath="name"/>
                    </StackPanel>

                    <!-- Items -->
                    <Grid Margin="5" Grid.Column="2">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding name, Source={StaticResource TypesCV}}"/>
                        <ListBox x:Name="PopupProductList" 
                                 ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ProductsCV}}" 
                                 SelectionMode="Multiple"
                                 Grid.Row="1"
                                 >
                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <!-- Product item -->
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" />
                                        <!--List of PDF items-->
                                        <ListBox x:Name="PopupProductPDFList" 
                                                 Grid.Row="1" 
                                                 DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                                                 ItemsSource="{Binding PDFItems}">
                                        </ListBox>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListBox>
                    </Grid>
```

However, i'm getting these errors:

Error: BindingExpression path error: 'Types' property not found on 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.ICollectionView'. BindingExpression: Path='Types' DataItem='Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.ICollectionView'; target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.CollectionViewSource' (Name='null'); target property is 'Source' (type 'Object')
Error: BindingExpression path error: 'Products' property not found on 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.ICollectionView'. BindingExpression: Path='Products' DataItem='Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.ICollectionView'; target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.CollectionViewSource' (Name='null'); target property is 'Source' (type 'Object')
Error: BindingExpression path error: 'name' property not found on 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.ICollectionView'. BindingExpression: Path='name' DataItem='Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.ICollectionView'; target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBlock' (Name='null'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
Error: BindingExpression path error: 'Title' property not found on 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.ICollectionView'. BindingExpression: Path='Title' DataItem='Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.ICollectionView'; target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBlock' (Name='null'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

Can anyone explain to me what i'm doing wrong here? I know it seems to be looking for a property on the collection view that isn't there, but how does the MS sample work, and why is everything "working" for the most part? I may be missing something fundamental here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the "errors" after following the exact tutorial on the website provided.  It is well-known that when dealing with XAML, you may come across errors that don't make sense, and in reality aren't really errors.  It might be a bug in VS, it may be the order of controls/resources being loaded, etc.  In short, if everything works the way you expect, and you're seeing binding errors, don't fret.  As a matter of fact test the UI with your mouse/keyboard, and if the UI seems broken, **THEN** look at the output window.

I did try some things out to see if I could get rid of the errors completely, but that didn't happen in a timely manner.  In short, I'd say avoid using XAML to create static data and make sure you're using a MVVM approach and implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  I say this because you only get errors for the items that are trying to bind to `StaticResource` members it seems like; and of course I think your static data should be generated in the ViewModel or Model domain.

In the example you linked, I was able to remove some of the errors by changing the `ContentControl` in this type of fashion:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource Teams}}">
<ContentControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <StackPanel Margin="5">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                       FontSize="15"
                       FontWeight="Bold" />
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                        Margin="10,10">
                <TextBlock Text="Wins:"
                           Margin="0,0,5,0" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Wins}" />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                        Margin="10,0">
                <TextBlock Text="Losses:"
                           Margin="0,0,5,0" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Losses}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ContentControl.Template>
```

**TL;DR:** You're doing nothing wrong. Microsoft's example doesn't "work" either.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `Types` or `Products` properties in `CollectionViewSource` to which you are trying to bind.